# How can Rfc2898DeriveBytes be both "based on HMACSHA1" and accept a hash algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, pbkdf2

[The docs for Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-7.0) say:

> Implements password-based key derivation functionality, PBKDF2, by
> using a pseudo-random number generator based on HMACSHA1.

but [the constructors that are not obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-7.0#constructors) all accept a hash algorithm.

Is that a contradiction or am I missing something?

Comment: It's a contradiction. It might be based on HMAC, but not HMAC-SHA1. dotnet cryptography documentation is a tragedy in my opinion, this is perhaps the least troubling problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [RFC (2898)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt). HMAC-SHA-1 is just one possible pseudorandom function.

> The default pseudorandom function is HMAC-SHA-1

> A hash function may also meet the requirements of a pseudorandom
> function under certain assumptions. For instance, the direct
> application of a hash function to to the concatenation of the "key"
> and the "text" may be appropriate, provided that "text" has
> appropriate structure to prevent certain attacks. HMAC-SHA-1 is
> preferable, however, because it treats "key" and "text" as separate
> arguments and does not require "text" to have any structure.

Comment: Yes. So that implies that the docs are wrong. But maybe the .net version (in my question) really does use SHA1 only, and perhaps stretches the result with the received algorithm, or maybe something else.

Comment: @ispiro Just a docs bug.  Apparently when I added the constructors that accepted the hash algorithm as a choice I missed that the docs said SHA-1 in the class summary.